# How to send "alt-s" via iTerm2 Python API

Tags: python, iterm2

The iTerm2 Python API provides async_send_text, which accepts a string. I can send the "s" character to the current session as input, but I want to know how to simulate pressing "alt-s" on the keyboard. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import iterm2

async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
    s = app.current_terminal_window.current_tab.current_session
    await s.async_send_text('s')


iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current API does not accept keytstrokes with modifiers like ALT. From https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/8387

> Most of the time it's better to use an API call if one is available instead of sending a keystroke, since keystrokes only work some of the time (e.g., if keyboard focus is in the prefs panel then Cmd-D won't do anything).