# iTerm2 Python API Split Tab

Tags: iterm2

Using the [iTerm Python API](https://www.iterm2.com/python-api/) added in the [3.3.0](https://iterm2.com/downloads/stable/iTerm2-3_3_0.changelog) release, is it possible to *split* a tab horizontally?
The same as;

> Right Click -> Split Pane Horizontally

---

```py
import iterm2

async def main(connection):

    # Get app
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)

    # current window
    window = app.current_terminal_window
    if window is not None:

        # Create main & sub tab
        main = await window.async_create_tab()
        await main.async_set_title('~ MAIN ~')
        sub = await window.async_create_tab()
        await sub.async_set_title('~ SUB ~')

        # Split sub
        ...
```

---

Sending the default keystroke (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>) [doesn't seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61644605/how-to-send-alt-s-via-iterm2-python-api).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[iTerm Python API](https://www.iterm2.com/python-api/) has an [`async_split_pane`](https://iterm2.com/python-api/session.html#iterm2.Session.async_split_pane) method that can split panes:

```py
tab = await window.async_create_tab()
session = tab.current_session
splited = await session.async_split_pane(vertical=False)
```

Session is responsible for splitting a tab.
If you want to split the newly created pane then do following:

```py
await splited.async_activate()
await session2.async_split_pane(vertical=True)
```

Your example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
    
import iterm2


async def main(connection):

    # Get app
    print("Test::main")
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)

    # Ensure window
    window = app.current_terminal_window
    if app.current_terminal_window is None:
        exit()

    # Create main tab
    main = await window.async_create_tab()
    await main.async_activate()
    await main.async_set_title('~ Title ~')
    sess = main.current_session

    # Split main
    sub = await sess.async_split_pane(vertical=True)
    await sub.async_send_text('whoami\n')

iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Tnx Mark for suggestion. I've fixed

Comment: Thanks for you answer, unfortunately I cant get it to work with your examples. Could you please extend my code to a working state?

Comment: I have updated the code 2 months ago. Did you manage to try it?

Comment: My apologies for the late response. Many thanks for your answer, works great! +1!

Comment: Just one note, from the second code block; `async_split_pane` returns a session, so no need to call `.current_session`